# Flyout not being displayed

Tags: html, css

I have two buttons placed side by side with the left button expanding to fill the space

```
.left {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  width: auto;
}
.right {
  float: right;
  width: 34px;
}
<div class="right" />
<div class="left" />
```

It took a long time to get even that working. Finally I figured out the left side needed `overflow: hidden` to correctly fill the space.

Now, the left button requires a flyout form on hover. The problem is I cannot get it to display while the container has the `overflow: hidden` style associated. Without this style the left side will expand to fill the full space including that of the right. How can I resolve this?

Flyout code

```
#login-flyout form {
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 66px;
    width: 250px;
}
#login-flyout form:hover {
    height: auto;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Please note, code works if `overflow: hidden` is removed from container.

Also, and this is the bain of my CSS experience, is there any reference I can look at with regards to container and contained styles? For example I wasted 3 hours yesterday trying to figure out how to auto expand a center `div` between two `float divs`. Turns out the problem was the container had a `float: right` style so the center `div` required a `float: none`.

Comment: The code given is just for reference

Comment: No, it is not valid HTML

Comment: Can you add your code to http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: I believe we will at least need the code for the flyout you described including its CSS and js

Comment: If you know how wide the rightmost button will be - in this case, 34px - you can do away with the `overflow:hidden` on the left one and use `margin-right:34px` instead to keep them from overlapping.

Comment: @MrLister As it happens that is exactly what I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Have a look at this solution → http://jsfiddle.net/matbloom/8cYFU/**

If you're looking for a CSS-only solution fly-out, then try implementing this solution. The hidden fly-out needs to be inside the hover element container:

HTML:

```
<div class="toolbar clearfix">
    <div class="right">
        <span>Right Button</span>
    </div>
    <div class="left">
        <span>Left Button</span>
        <div id="login-flyout">
            <form>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Sample field" /><br />
                <input type="text" placeholder="Sample field" /><br />
                <input type="submit" value="GO &rarr;" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body, input {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 15px;
    color: #333;
}

.left, .right {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 40px;
    display: block;
    background: #ccc;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.left:hover, .right:hover {
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
}

.left { float: left; }
.right { float: right; }

.toolbar {
    background: #eee;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

#login-flyout {
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    left: 0;
    top: 40px;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #333;
}

.left:hover #login-flyout { display: block; }

/* Clearfix */

.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.clearfix { display: inline-block; }
html[xmlns] .clearfix { display: block; }
* html .clearfix {height: 1%;}
```